# how to rewrite multiple and single params in url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url like this

```
http://be.ac/index.php?category=all&providers=all&keyword=cookies&page=1
```

I want to rewrite like this:

```
http://be.ac/category/all/providers/all/keyword:cookies/page:1
```

this is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page:([^/]*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?category=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/page:([^/]*)/? index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/providers/([^/]*)/page:([^/]*)? index.php?category=$1&providers=$2&page=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/providers/([^/]*)/keyword:([^/]*)/page:([^/]*)? index.php?category=$1&providers=$2&keyword=$3&page=$4 [QSA,L]
```

this is not working, what I need is accept urls like this:

```
http://be.ac/category/all/providers/all/keyword:cookies/page:1
http://be.ac/category/all/providers/all/page:1
http://be.ac/category/all/page:1
http://be.ac/page:1
http://be.ac/keyword:cookies
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with regards to colons. First guess is that they would need to be encoded, unless in a hash-string.

As such, you'd be getting a *403 Forbidden* error thrown - though, you have not specified in your question.

The only thing I can recommend is switching out those colons for forward slashes, which keeps the URI consistent (like you have done with `category/<something>` instead of `category:<something>`):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/page/([^/]+)/? index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/providers/([^/]+)/page/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&providers=$2&page=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/providers/([^/]+)/keyword/([^/]+)/page/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&providers=$2&keyword=$3&page=$4 [QSA,L]
```

Also, I've changed `([^/]*)` to `([^/]+)`, and fixed the trailing slash issue with the last two issues (they were inconsistent with the others).